# Blender layer weight material to Unity

Tags: unity, blender, materials

How to set in Unity this Blender material with layer weight node?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycles render engine work totally different than Unity (this is valid for almost every combination of 3D software), so there is **only one way how to ship pixel informations from Blender to Unity: using textures/maps.** Another problem with Unity is, there are no material editor, so you need to **bake everything in Blende**r and import final maps to Unity. This can be really painful in case Blender-Unity, because is impossible adjust anything in Unity. Also this is topic for a book. For simple materials, just **bake colors/albedo and normal**, for PBS prepare for long way until you find out, it does not make sense and you look for Substance Live

EDIT: Short version: What do you want is impossible.

Comment: How to add radial gradent color in Unity material section? This could be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Wildfire As I wrote: no material editor in Unity, so you need bake textures it Blender and use them in Unity. There is no other way how to transfer material data and behavior from Blender to Unity. In your particular case your can code your own custom shader or download/buy it. But generally, you can't export material from Cycles and use it in Unity.